Prokhorov's theorem for countably many random measures on a Polish space
I am looking for help to show the following lemma:

Lemma Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P)$ be a complete, standard Borel probability space and $\mathcal X$ a Polish space. Let $\mathcal P(\mathcal X)$ be the set of probability measures on $\mathcal X$ equipped with the topology of weak convergence. Let $\mathcal Q = \{P_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ be a countable collection of random measures on $\mathcal X$.
Assume that the set $E=\{\mathcal Q\text{ is closed and sequentially compact}\}\subset \Omega$ is measurable and has probability 1.
Then, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a random compact subset $K_\epsilon$ of $\mathcal X$ such that $P_n(K_\epsilon) \geq 1 - \epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a.s.

Some comments:

$\mathcal X$ is equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\mathcal X)$
I define a random measure as a Markov kernel from $\mathcal B(\mathcal X)\times \Omega$ to $[0,1]$, as in [Kal17]
Random compact sets are measurable maps $(\Omega,\mathcal A)\to (\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{X}),\mathcal B(\tau))$, where $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal X)$ is the set of nonempty compact subsets of $\mathcal X$ equipped with $\tau$ is an appropriate topology and the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebra. So far, I have worked with the topology of the Hausdorff distance $\tau_h$, but I'm not sure this is the most appropriate choice.

In the case of a collection of non-random measures, the lemma immediately follows from Prokhorov's theorem. The challenge is to show the existence of a measurable choice of the compact set.
My idea is to use the Kuratowksi-Ryll-Nardzewski measurable selection theorem .
Specifically, let $A:\Omega \to \mathcal F(\mathcal K(\mathcal X)))$ be defined for $\omega\in\Omega$ as $$A(\omega) = \begin{cases}
\{K\in\mathcal K(\mathcal X)\mid\forall P\in\mathcal Q, P_\omega (K) \geq 1- \epsilon\},&\text{if }\omega\in E,\\
\{L\},\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
where $L$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathcal K(\mathcal X)$ and $\mathcal F(\mathcal K(\mathcal X))$ the set of nonempty closed subsets of $\mathcal K(\mathcal X)$ equipped with the Fell topology.
I need to show weak measurability of $A$.
My questions are:

Do you have suggestions to show weak measurability of $A$, or to show the lemma using any other method?
Is this lemma true? Or does the desired result require more assumptions? For instance, a stronger assumption still acceptable for me is locally compact $\mathcal{X}$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I summarize below my attempt for the sake of discussion, even though it is not conclusive.
I omit details for conciseness but am happy to fill blanks if you think it's necessary.

Write $A(\omega) = \bigcap_{P\in\mathcal{Q}} A_P(\omega),$ where $A_P(\omega)$ is defined similarly to $A$ by replacing $\mathcal Q$ with $\{P\}$.
Leverage the fact that $A$ is in fact compact-valued to deduce that its measurability and weak measurability are equivalent (Theorem 19.2 in [AO16]), which entails that $A$ is measurable if all of the $A_P$ are. From now on, $P\in\mathcal Q$ is fixed.
Leverage the fact that for all $Q\in\mathcal P(\mathcal X)$, the map $e_Q:K\in\mathcal K(\mathcal X)\mapsto P(K)\in [0,1]$ is upper-semicontinuous w.r.t. the Hausdorff metric to obtain a measurable choice of functions $f_m:\Omega\times\mathcal K(\mathcal X)\to [0,1]$ such that
(i) $f_m(\omega,\cdot) \to P_\omega(\cdot)$, pointwise as $m\to\infty$;
(ii) $f_m \geq P$; and
(iii) $f_m(\omega,\cdot)$ is continuous.
Show that the maps $B_m:\Omega\to\mathcal F(\mathcal K(\mathcal X))$ defined for $\omega\in E$ as $$B_m(\omega) = \{K\in\mathcal K(\mathcal X)\mid f_m (\omega, K) \geq 1- \epsilon\}$$ constitute a decreasing sequence of functions converging to $A_P$ in the Fell topology.

This manipulation essentially enables to replace $P$ in the definition of $A_P$ with an approximation that is continuous w.r.t. the Hausdorff distance: if all of the $B_m$'s are measurable, so is $A_P$. Note that this reasoning requires showing that the limit of measurable functions with values in $\mathcal F(\mathcal K(\mathcal X))$ is measurable, of which I am yet unsure.
But even then, I can't show measurability of the $B_m$'s.
Indeed, contrary to $A_P$, they are not compact-valued and thus their measurability is not equivalent to their weak measurability. And even if it were, I can't find a way to leverage continuity of $f_m(\omega, \cdot)$, since in general $$\begin{split}\hat B_m(U) := \{\omega\in\Omega\mid B_m(\omega)\cap U\neq \emptyset\} 
&= \{\omega\in\Omega\mid \exists K\in U, f_m(\omega, K)\geq 1-\epsilon\}\\
&\subsetneq \{\omega \in\Omega \mid\sup_{K\in U}f_m(\omega,K) \geq 1-\epsilon\}\\
&= \{\omega \in\Omega \mid\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}f_m(\omega,K_n) \geq 1-\epsilon\},
\end{split}$$
where $U$ is an open of $\mathcal K(\mathcal X))$ and $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a dense sequence of $U$ (which exists by separability of $\mathcal K(\mathcal X))$.
This equality would hold if $U$ were $\sigma$-compact, but I believe this comes at a loss of generality.
[Kal17] Random measures, theory and applications, Kallenberg, 2017
[AO16] Convex and set-valued analysis: selected topics, Arutyunov and Obukhovskii, 2016

I don't understand the definition of $E$.
